# To convert all null, undefined data inside an object into String data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to create a function that replaces empty data such as null value or undefined data with String value among the data of the object.

So I found this code and it works well in Jsfiddle. But When I apply to my object data, it has an error.

The error is from `repo object`. Actually, the data is from github API `https://api.github.com/users/writingdeveloper/repos` So the it will the same data as `repo object`

The error is from `repo.license.key` because some of the repos doesn't have repo.license, So it makes an error.

If I try do like this. It works 100% but, the code doesn't look nice. How can I fix this problem?

```
if (!repo.homepage) {
    repo.homepage = 'None'
}  if (!repo.language) {
   repo.language = 'None'
}  if (!repo.mirror_url) {
   repo.repo.mirror_url= 'None'
}
```

```
router.get(`/:userId/admin/mypage`, sessionCheck, (req, res, next) => {
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  Repo.find({
    'owner.login': userId
  }, function (err, repo) {
    if (err) throw err;

     function isNull(obj, key) {
         return (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined || obj[key] === "null");
     }
     function validate(obj) {
         var objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
         console.log(objKeys)
       objKeys.forEach((key) => {
         if(isNull(obj, key)) {
             obj[key] = "None";
         }
         if(typeof(obj[key]) == "object") {
             validate(obj[key]);
         }
       });
     }

     validate(repo);  // This function has an error.

    repo.map((repo) => {
      {

       (.....some image process.....)


        if (!repo.homepage) {
          repo.homepage = 'None'   // When I set each data to String data, it works.
        }
        if (!repo.language) {
          repo.language = 'None'   // When I set each data to String data, it works.
        }
      }
    })

    const sum = repo.reduce(function (prev, next) {
      return prev + next.detailViewCounter;
    }, 0);
    res.render('mypage/main', {
      userId: userId,
      dataArray: repo,
      todayVisitor: sum,
      updatedTime: updatedTime.toLocaleString()
    })
  })
```

Comment: Do you manage server side code too? If yes, you can send those default values from backend. What do you reckon?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must check its type. For that use typeof

```
const list = []
const count = 2

typeof list //"object"
typeof count //"number"
typeof "test" //"string"

typeof color //"undefined"
const car = {
  model: 'Fiesta'
}
typeof car.color // color is undefined
```